# How to remote linux desktop with audio support

Tags: linux, debian, remote-desktop

I have a Debian PC(Server) and I would like to remote this machine from one client(Window, Ubuntu,..) and i can hear the sound from Server.

I try some tools(Radmin, RealVNC,..)(I can not use Teamviewer cause of pricing) but I can not transfer sound from server to client.

So, my question is what tool can solve this issue?

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Teamviewer is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: @martineau We are in commercial use :-)

Answer (score 8):

My Remminia version is 1.4.2, on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

It works for me to change **Advanced** => **Sound** from *Off* to *Local - high quality*.

Comment: Even with 1.3 this brings the sound for Me. I tried all Local options. Simple "Local", and "Local - low quality" sounds poor, and clicky. "Local - high quality" is enjoyable, and between them is also acceptable.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10, this still works.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: The following answer is not valid for Remmina versions greater than 1.1.0 as the sound options seems to be gone.

Remmina is a remote desktop client written in GTK+, aiming to be useful for system administrators and travellers, who need to work with lots of remote computers in front of either large monitors or tiny netbooks. Remmina supports multiple network protocols in an integrated and consistent user interface. Currently RDP, VNC, NX, XDMCP and SSH are supported.

One of my chief complaints with some of the other RDP clients available for managing  desktops from Linux is the poor remote audio support. Although you can generally ‘get’ sound to work, you won’t like what it sounds like. Remmina handles remote sound beautifully, clearly giving you the option of leaving your audio in place or ‘bringing’ it to your desktop, see the options screen below:

[image]

Comment: In Remmina 1.1.2 seems that option is gone. No option related to Sound.

Comment: I think this answer should be edited to include @chomp's comment on the first line. I don't know if 1.1.2 is the first version where that option disappeared, but it's definitely no there in 1.4.7.

Comment: The option is still there, but you have to make the changes before the connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to record experience here.  Have used remmina 1.1.2 for years and had remote sound w/no configuration or special setup.  suddenly stopped working from ubuntu clients (windows mstsc clients could still get sound fine).   also whenever you'd adjust the sound via ubuntu, it would hang a bit.   no updates to os/client.

completely closing remmina and restarting it seemed to fix it.

obviously pretty basic solution but easy to miss bc it tends to stick around in system tray.  hopefully this helps somebody.

Comment: this actually resolved an issue where sound worked in my headset... but redirect microhone failed in remote teams meeting. I think on sleep/resume or on boot, the microphone isn't available, some pulse race condition. So I'm removing Remmina applet from Session.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Reminna (Feb 2022), you can find Sound option in Advance tab.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jHD1.png)

Answer (score -1):

The answer, for any that come after, is that you have to go to the advanced options and enable sound before connecting to the computer.  The advanced options are disabled after the connection is established

Answer (score -1):

I was experiencing this problem with Remmina 1.4.21 on Fedora 35 and was able to resolve the problem doing the following:

1. `Disconnect` from the current remote session
2. Right-click your `Connection Profile` -> `Edit` -> `Advanced`
3. `Audio output mode` -> Change to `Local` -> `Save`

**Note**: If you don't have a `Connection Profile`, there should be a button somewhere to create one. In my instance, it is in the upper left, `New connection profile`

**Regarding the sound quality**: I had to remote into a Win10 machine and I notice the sound is **echoey, VERY distorted, and "metallic" sounding** using `Local` audio. I just need a basic notification noise for a task I run occasionally.

You *could* set the audio output mode to `Remote` if you wish to use the speakers from the device you are remoting into, but you won't be able to hear them through your `Local` speakers or headphones. (This might be a good option if you're just trying to play music from a different room and the remote machine's speakers are very good.)